# save each row of dictionary array to numpy(.npy) file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list and dictionary like below and want to save each row of dictionary as numpy file.

```
lists=['first_data','second_data']
```

```
dict_array=
{'1': array([[1., 1., 2., 2.], #here represents'first_data'
[3., 3., 4., 4.]]), #here represents 'second data'
 '2': array([[10., 1., 21., 1.], #here represents'first_data'
[24., 12., 32., 33.]])} #here represents 'second data'
```

For each row in each array, I want to save it as numpy file with it's name on it.

For example,
for **dict_array['1']**, the first row should have **'1_first_data.npy'**, and for **dict_array['2']**, the second row should have **'2_second_data.npy'**.

I only read each row of dictionary but need help for next steps.

```
for i,a in dict_array.items():
   for row in a:
      row.tofile(str...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for key, values in dict_array.items():
     [np.save(f'{key}_{label}.npy', value) for (label, value) in zip(lists, values)]
```

I implemented it such that you could also add a `'third_data'` to your dictionary since the list comprehension iterates over all arrays that are given in the values of your dictionary.